# VS 2015 installing curl/libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2015, libcurl

I have read dozens of posts and blogs regarding this very issue, but as common as the problem seems to be I cannot really find any documentation that has helped me install curl for my C++ projects in VS 2015. Basically, after linking all of the dependencies, etc. I am still getting C1083 errors telling me that "curl.h" cannot be found, and so of course nothing will work.

I have been using this post as my starting point: https://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/

So I have downloaded several different releases, including older versions, and while I now have many of the files from the example above I still do not seem to have everything. This is what I finally ended up with:

```
C:\curl
  - bin
      - curl.exe
      - curl-ca-bundle.crt
  - dlls
      - libcurl.dll
      - libeay32.dll
      - libssh2.dll
      - msvcr110.dll
      - ssleay32.dll
      - zlib1.dll
  - include\curl
      - curl.h
      - curlbuild.h
      - curlrules.h
      - curlver.h
      - easy.h
      - mprintf.h
      - multi.h
      - stdcheaders.h
      - typecheck-gcc.h
  - lib
      - libcurl.exp
      - libcurl.lib
```

The lib files here, in particular, do not match any of the file names from the posts, but as all of the downloads seem to vary I cannot be sure if that is causing my problem.

In my test project, I have specified the following configuration properties:

```
VC++ -> Include Directories -> C:\curl\include;C:\curl\include\curl;

C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\curl\include;C:\curl\include\curl;

Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> C:\curl\lib;

Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> C:\curl\lib\libcurl.lib;
```

And then after setting up the project, I added "C:\curl\bin" to my environment variables.

At this point I really cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. If I copy "curl.h" into my test project, the error goes away (obviously I get a pile of new errors though), so I am obviously not properly linking everything. And at this point I am stuck.

I only occassionally add new libraries, etc. to my projects, so it is always somewhat frustrating. The lack of (current) documentation makes this even more painful than usual.

Anyway, thanks in advance for any hep getting me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

I had the same problem. It is really frustrating when it comes to including stuff in Visual Studio. I searched a lot and wasted big time since the problem is very wide and every online post is different in a way. Not cool. I reached a wall with LibcURL until I found that guy who helped me step by step on how to include it. Somewhere in the forum - See next pages - I posted all steps on "how to include libcURL" in one post in a complete clean way so readers can take advantage of it instead of wasting time with the whole discussion.

Either read all posts or just search for that golden post and good luck!

[**HERE IS MY FORUM QUESTION**](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/173738/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I am still reading through your post, but I am still very confused about where I need to find these .lib files and Debug directory etc - it looks like you had the same problem. I have found this older download (https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/curl/7.44.0/view) to try to match your version. Still, I am lost.

Comment: So I think I have set everything up as described in Wyboth's notes, but instead I used the most recent version (7.47.1) to build the library. The build seems to have worked correctly, and after moving the new include & lib files, etc. I added the additional directories & links to the configuration properties. Unfortunately VS is still unable to find the header files. *&^$&*^@*&#&!!!

Comment: So why the new version? What version did I use? Try whatever version I used

Comment: I will check if I still have it once I go home

Comment: I finally figured it out! I had to play around with the "configurations" at the very top of the "properties" menu. I wish I had been paying more attention a the time, but basically I made sure all of the links & dependencies where the same for each configuration (active, debug & release). I think I also needed to check that "x64" was selected for the "platform", but I wasn't taking notes. I did have another problem while using the static build, but when I switched to the dynamic it worked as expected. I'll try to resolve the new issue later, but I'm eager to start working with the library now.

Comment: Good to hear that. Enjoy !